# How do you find your port for Minecraft LAN worlds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've looked at a lot of websites and the ports are either outdated or don't show how to find it. I know how to get into the cmd thing and all that, but I cannot find my port for the life of me. Is it always the same thing or randomized?

Comment: There have been many questions like this are you sure that one of those doesn't answer you problem?

Comment: From what I can tell, you are _not_ trying to open a LAN world, but a _server_. A _server_ requires you to open ports on your router, and, without proper knowledge, you can very much screw up your network. The difference between LAN world and a server open to the internet is that a LAN world is only open to those who exist on _your wifi_, not the world. If you're seeking to be able to access this world outside of your current wifi, [follow the link to this Arqade question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19780/how-can-i-host-my-own-minecraft-server). If you mean LAN, my other answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you hit <kbd>/</kbd> inside the world just after you open it to LAN, it will show you what port it opened on.

Answer (score 3):

In game, type: [`/publish`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/publish) then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It will send a message including the port.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my answer on your other (related) question, if you *truly mean LAN worlds*, you do not need to know this information. LAN worlds automatically configure this for you. Your port is shown directly next to the local IP address:

[image]

Anything behind a `:` in an address specifies a port number.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>T</kbd> to open the console. You will see recent messages - like the one telling you your server's port.