# How do you join a Minecraft world without a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Me and my bro have wanted to join in Minecraft pc to mac without a server and we can't figure it out can you help us?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I host my own Minecraft server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19780/how-can-i-host-my-own-minecraft-server)

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate -- "without a server" doesn't lead me to think that "host my own Minecraft server" is the answer. Perhaps joining a LAN game?

Comment: @TimS. If you look at the accepted answer to that question, the first option is "open to LAN".

Comment: @pppery Editing this - misunderstood.. I missed that part I guess. I see your point.

Answer (score 5):

Technically speaking, you can't join a Minecraft world on your computer without some form of server.

However, provided two computers are on the same LAN (or WiFi or whatever), one of them can connect to the other's world and play in it without the need for dedicated server software. To do this, just go to the pause menu (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) and click the **Open To LAN** button. You will be asked a couple of questions, but you can just click through without changing anything.

From there, a special type of server will appear under the "Multiplayer" category of the other computer. This is the LAN world being hosted by another computer. Join that "server," and you will both be in the same game/world.

Comment: Note that if Java is not allowed through the host's firewall in this scenario, the people joining would either get timed out when trying to join or the host's game will not show up to the other(s) on the network. Also it must be the SAME EXACT router / access point (ones in "relay" mode will work too if it is still for the same access point / router -- technically speaking, same local network IP address pool)

Comment: To follow up, systems that simulate a LAN over the internet will also work... but introduce latency and other problems (like higher chance of packet loss)