# For minecraft, what application type is minecraft when making a PC sever?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

So I'm making, or at least trying to, a minecraft PC server.  Now I'm not going to play with per say, at least not yet.  So I'm asking is when port forwarding on my At&t u-verse router, what should I add as the program type? Port wise, I'll figure it out.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by type of application.

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server this should get you started. Minecraft PC en Minecraft PE are NOT the same application and you can't host 1 server for both. They each need their separate server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I host my own Minecraft server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19780/how-can-i-host-my-own-minecraft-server)

Comment: Errr... I'm getting five different questions where three makes no sense here...

Comment: Does the  'Application Type' matter? A port is a port - it just sounds like your router gives you the option of some meta-information so you know why you opened that port when you next look at it. You could probably get away with just setting it to 'Application' or something.

Answer (score 1):

The Minecraft PC (Java Edition) Server is, exactly like the game, a *Java Application*.

Due to how it is built, it uses an encrypted *TCP connection* **on port 25565** to communicate between the server and the clients.

You can learn more about how to set up a Minecraft Server at the MinecraftWiki: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server

You can get it [here](https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/server).

Comment: It might be worth specifically quoting the parts about [Port Forwarding](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Port_forwarding) as it sounds like that's where OP is getting stuck.

Comment: @Robotnik you are right, I added that to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Minecraft servers run in UDP mode when performing the port forwarding on your home network. Take this with a grain of salt as I haven't made a server in a while, but it should remain the same.