# how do me and my friend play minecraft on pc together on my or her world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

me and my friend wants to play Minecraft together on my or her world but we don't know how, we live in different buildings and she cant come over, she has a ps4 with Minecraft and i play Minecraft on a pc.

Answer (score 1):

You can not cross play PS4 with PC version.  [Click Here](https://gamerant.com/minecraft-dlc-ps4-cross-play/undefined) or [here](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/new-ps4-version-of-minecraft-with-cross-play-suppo/1100-6452154/) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

You can host your own server, and send your friend the server ip and play on that server at the same time. If you need help hosting your own server, try reading this: [How can I host my own Minecraft server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19780/how-can-i-host-my-own-minecraft-server?noredirect=1&lq=1)