# Can I have a friend connect to my world without using Minecraft Realms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

If I create a Minecraft world (not server) on my computer, will a friend that isn't where I am be able to play in that world?

I am talking about Minecraft for PC. Note that I am only asking about a normal world, not a server. Also, this is without Minecraft realms.

Comment: Is it possible?  Yeah.  Is it convenient and should you do it?  No.  Get a server (or set one up at home).  It's going to be so much better for both of you, and is the only option if you want to be able to have both of you on at the same time.

Comment: What about logmein Hamachi?

Comment: Can you tell me more about Hamachi?

Comment: @redapple8787 unfortunately I do not know much about networking, but it is (as far as I know) a program that allows devices to directly connect over the internet. I used it to play Terraria with people in other locations.

Comment: Hamachi is a vpn service that allows different devices to pretend as if they are in the same network, allowing them to find eachother using a newly assigned ip address. This system allows a player to host a private world for other people, without having to mess with router ports and such.

Comment: Related: [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19780/how-can-i-host-my-own-minecraft-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19780/how-can-i-host-my-own-minecraft-server)

Comment: Just wondering, why all of the down votes? I'd like some feedback.

Comment: @redapple8787 first of all: you don't show effort. We want to see that you have tried to solve this yourself. If you show us what you have tried, then we can answer you better. Secondly: you are person 1001 who asks this question. Not literally ofcourse, but many people ask this and a simple google search will give you all the answers.

Comment: @D-Inventor Thank you. I'll take a look on Google to see if it is possible.

Comment: If you're going to the effort of setting up Hamachi, you may as well just set up a Minecraft server...

Comment: @Studoku That looks like a duplicate rather than just related to me. Both questions are asking "How can I make it so that other people can connect to my world in Minecraft?"

Comment: @pppery & VTCers: this is not a duplicate. This question explicitly _excludes_ servers.

Comment: @Schism That's irrelevant since the top answer to the possible duplicate starts out with "Open to LAN"

Comment: @pppery It is entirely relevant. The answers to a question have no bearing on whether some question duplicates another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible without creating a server, you are able to do this by opening your world to-LAN. Then port forwarding you Computer's Local IP and the port created by opening to LAN. Then giving your Public IP to your friend. This may seem confusing, let me demonstrate.

If you are on Windows you can find your Computer's Local IP by opening Command Prompt (CMD) and typing "ipconfig" and then pressing enter.

If you are on Mac you can find you Computer's Local IP by opening System Preferences and selecting "network".

[image: How to find Mac Local IP]

Make sure that your Minecraft World is opened to LAN

[image]

You can find out how to Port Forward [here](https://portforward.com/).
**NOTE**: When entering the port, the port will be the one that is in the chat in Minecraft.

You can find your public IP by googling, "Whats My IP"

Now all you have to do is give your friend the IP. **NOTE**: The format in which you enter the IP into Minecraft is "IP:PORT". An Example is "192.168.0.1:25565".

Comment: I will try this out when I can (I am quite busy) and I will see if it works. This is an interesting method.

Comment: Okay, ask if you need help and it does work as I have tested before.